# Can 20pin PSU cause usb stick corruption

Tags: usb, power-supply

Getting constant usb stick corruption issues when using an old 200W PSU with 20pins with both NTFS and FAT32. Can the old PSU cause the corruption? PC is running fine otherwise (no BSOD, freezes).

Comment: Are you asking if the way your PSU is connected to your mainboard can have an affect on the consistency of a file system of a USB drive?

Comment: I would think if the PC is otherwise working ok then the power supply is unlikely to be the cause of your problems.

Answer (score 0):

1. you can also use a live CD distribution of linux to try to copy files in USB stick and see if they are corrupt. If no, then the problem must be in the Operating system
2. Did the corruption occur in a single disk. If so, then try a different drive and see if it gets corrupt too. If it doesn't get corrupt, then the problem is in your USB drive.
3. you can Use a voltmeter to check if the supply voltage of the USB port is 5V. If it is not constant 5V, then PSU might be a problem.
4. What sort of hardware are you driving with the PSU? If you have a dual core processor, most likely, the PSU is over exhausted. Then you might consider replacing it. If possible, try to open up an extra RAM, excess harddrives and optical drives, and just connect the USB to see if data corruption persists. If no, then your PSU was overloaded.

Comment: #1 Corruption doesn't occur immediately. Sometimes it takes weeks before there is an issue.

Comment: #2 Has occurred with three different brand disks.
#3 According to HWMonitor, 5V is stable - shows 5.03V
#4 Old Pentium dual core e2180 undervolted to 0.9V, 4GB DDR2 plus a 4W HDD and G31 chipset (GA-G31M-ES2L). This setup consumes at best 50W at load, so load is unlikely to be an issue.